# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' al intentar cargar datos str de un archivo csv a una funcion fit() para entrenar un modelo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, data-atributos

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv',sep=';') #Cargo el archivo csv

x = df.iloc[1:,1:] #features values
y = df.iloc[1:,0] #target value

print(x)
print(y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

print(x_train)
print(y_train)

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier

pipelines = {
    'lr':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression()),
    'rc':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RidgeClassifier()),
    'rf':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier()),
    'gb':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier()),
}

fit_models = {}

for algo, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
    fit_models[algo] = model

print(fit_models)

print(fit_models['lr'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['rc'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['rf'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['gb'].predict(x_test))
```

Al cargar los siguientes datos donde los encuadrados en rojo corresponden a los targets que son strings, y se cargan en la variable `y`, y los encuadrados en azul son las features que son floats y van almacenados en la variable `x`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy teniendo el problema de que me sale el siguiente error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_Train_Custom_Model_Using_Scikit_Learn.py", line 99, in <module>
    model = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 335, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 1407, in fit
    fold_coefs_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1041, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 859, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 777, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 572, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 762, in _logistic_regression_path
    n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py", line 243, in _check_optimize_result
    ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Que es lo que esta dando ese error? Acaso son los nombres de las str que se hallan en el y_train? o los floats que se hallan en x_train al pasarles al fit() ?

Ademas como haria para cargar los datos del archivo csv que vienen como str, y luego llevarlos a cadena de bytes, para evitar este error de decode?

Y si uso el metodo `y = y.apply(lambda y: y.encode())` en la variable `y` que contiene los targets, me sale este error de `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_Train_Custom_Model_Using_Scikit_Learn.py", line 99, in <module>
    model = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 335, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 1345, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    y_type = type_of_target(y)
  File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 263, in type_of_target
    raise ValueError('You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data'
ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.
```

Comment: Para transformar una cadena de strings a bytes solo tienes que hacer uso del método  `.encode()`

Comment: eso lo entiendo el problema es que no se como adaptarlo a este codigo, supongo que eso se lo tendria que aplicar a `y_train`  que son str (y para `x_train` no seria necesario), pero el problema es que `y_train` seria una especie de lista de strings, no? deberia aplicar eso a cada elemento? no se si un ciclo for serviria para esa tarea

Comment: cual es la variable que contiene strings?

Comment: bueno creo que es la variable `x`. Como esta es una serie, puedes usar el método `apply` de esta forma `x = x.apply(lambda y: y.encode())`

Comment: He probado eso pero aplicado a la `y` porque es la que tiene los nombres de los targets ('Happy','Sad','Surprice',etc....), pero me sale un error de `the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.` por eso tenia duda acerca de como pasar a bytes array de datos. De todos modos ahi actualize mi pregunta con el error que te comento completo.

Comment: tal vez te sirva [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34213199/15026532) en el sitio en Ingles

Comment: gracias, la vere ahora, aunque se me esta complicando bastante este code en general. Y ahora el tema del binarizado del array me esta confundiendo un poco.

Comment: Lastimosamente no soy ningún experto en maching learning  hay pocos en Stack Overflow  que sepan de esto, uno de ellos es Rubiales Alberto pero hace tiempo no lo veo

Comment: @Christian Muchas gracias igual ;)